# Insert quotation marks around date near end of string in perl with regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have lines of data being read into an array in perl that looks like this:

```
aaa bbb    ccc ddd -
aaa bbb ccc ddd    eee -
```

I am trying to inject quotation marks around specific fields in each line- the secont to last and third to last. I'd like the lines to look like this when I'm done:

```
aaa bbb    "ccc ddd" -
aaa bbb ccc "ddd    eee" -
```

I've tried splitting the line into an array and using the @array[-3] notation, but that split gets rid of all the whitespace being used as a delimiter. I think I need to use a backreference with a substitution- something like:

```
s/(\s+[^\s]*\s+)$/\"$+\"/
```

Except I can't figure out how to make that match the specific fields I need and skip the last ones. Currently, it's putting the last quotation mark after the newline.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```regex
\w+\s+\w+(?=\s-)
```

**Replace With:** `"$0"`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/dO1oU9/1

**Sample text**

```
aaa bbb    ccc ddd -
aaa bbb ccc ddd    eee -
```

**After Replacement**

```
aaa bbb    "ccc ddd" -
aaa bbb ccc "ddd    eee" -
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm really still quite new to regex- I thought I needed to use backreferences to replace something. If I do a like in perl like `$var =~ s/\w+\s+\w+(?=\s-)/$0/`, will it by default match the whole string?

Comment: And another question- if I wanted to allow the last column to be anything, not just a dash, would changing it to \w+$ work, like this: `$var =~ s/\w+\s+\w+(?=\s+\w+$)/$0/`?

Comment: first question: the lookahead `(?=\s-)` simply looks ahead to see if the next characters are a space followed by a dash. The look ahead simply looks to see if those are then next characters but it doesn't include them in the capture.  Also the search function in perl is just `s/...../` in your question the trailing `$0/` would be used if you're running a replace. but replacing the entire found string with $0 would yield no changes.

Comment: Second question: Yes if you changed `(?=\s+\w+$)` the last column could contain any number of a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and `_` characters. The last column would not be included in the match of course, it would simply be tested to see if it exists.

Comment: I thought in order to use the match, you needed to capture it with backreferences. So `$var =~ s/\w+\s+\w+(?=\s+\w+$)/\"$0\"/` would have the effect I'm going for?

Comment: The syntax looks similar but a lookahead `(?=....)`  simply checks to see if the enclosed expression matches but does not include that match in the capture, whereas a capture group like `(....)` not only captures matching text for the overall main capture, but also creates an additional seperate capture group for just that sub match.

Answer (score 1):

Demonstrated here: https://regex101.com/r/zD3cP9/2

With the pattern

```
((?:\w+\s*){2})(\s+-)
```

executed on

```
aaa bbb    ccc ddd -
aaa bbb ccc ddd    eee -
```

would be

```
aaa bbb    "ccc ddd" -
aaa bbb ccc "ddd    eee" -
```

This one repeats the first subpattern twice as it looks for a dash to complete it. Useful because it is easily maintainable.

Comment: Thank you! So if I understand this, the first part `(?:\w+\s*){2}` is a lookahead looking for a word and then 0 or more spaces twice, and the second part matches whitespace then a dash?

Comment: You'll have to be careful with this type of expression because the `\s*` will allow zero or more spaces... and running that twice is like saying, find a string with 1 or more characters followed by 0 or more spaces, followed by 1 or more characters followed by 0 or more spaces. In other words a two character word like `ab` could be matched by this expression because it contains zero spaces between the letters `a` and `b` and zero spaces after the letter `b`. This may lead to some unexpected results.